# Master equation approximation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, open-quantum-systems

In the Lindbladian master equation, one of the approximations is assuming $\rho(t)=\rho_S(t)\otimes\rho_B(t)$.

However, if we try to solve the total state in a numerical way, using $\dot{\rho}(t)=-i[H_{SB},\rho(t)]\,\,(H_{SB}=S(t)\otimes B(t))$, we get,

$\rho(t_1)-\rho(0)=-i\delta t\big(S(0)\rho_S(0)\otimes B(t)\rho_B(0)-\rho_S(0)S(0)\otimes \rho_B(0)B(0)\big)$

$\rho(t_1)=\rho(0)-i\delta t\big(S(0)\rho_S(0)\otimes B(t)\rho_B(0)-\rho_S(0)S(0)\otimes \rho_B(0)B(0)\big)\neq \rho_S(t_1)\otimes \rho_B(t_1)$

The above total state for $t=t_1$ does not seem separable.
Therefore, I do not understand how to justify $\rho(t)=\rho_S(t)\otimes\rho_B(t)$ condition.

Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 3):

It is only a good approximation if your initial state at the beginning of the evolution is separable:
$$
\rho(t_0) = \rho_S(t_0) \otimes \rho_B(t_0) 
$$

The argument goes like this: if you have no coupling between the system and environment then you would certainly just have $\rho(t) = \rho_S(t) \otimes \rho_B(t)$ for all $t$ (as system and environment evolve separately in that case).

This means that any non-separable part is perturbatively small, and proportional to the coupling (say $\lambda$) in $H_{SB}$. You can convince yourself by using the ansatz
$$
\rho(t) = \rho_S(t) \otimes \rho_B(t) + \lambda \rho^{(1)}_{\mathrm{corr}} + \lambda^2 \rho^{(2)}_{\mathrm{corr}} + \ldots
$$
You'll find that the master equation at leading order in the coupling doesn't care about the higher order correlations (you could track them with some effort if you wish though).

Answer (score 2):

The approximation $\rho(t) \approx \rho(t) \otimes \rho_B(t)$ is not done for arbitrary times. It is performed inside a time integral where there are autocorrelation functions of the baths. The assumption is that the autocorrelations decay on a time scale short enough that this approximation holds.

This assumption is not actually needed. I recommend the read of the derivation of the Lindblad master equation in the introduction section of this open-access paper, where the authors use the Zwanzing's and Nakajima's projection technique:
https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1367-2630/12/11/113032/meta